# Copying a String Array into a Range of cells (in MS Excel using VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I can use a `For` construct to loop through the string array elements and copy their contents into the individual cells of the range; but is there a simpler way to directly copy the string array items into the Range?

The question [Range to string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773232/excel-vba-range-to-string-array-in-1-step) solves the exact opposite of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this

```
Sub StringArrayToRange()

    Dim strArr(3) As String
    strArr(0) = "one"
    strArr(1) = "two"
    strArr(2) = "three"

    Range("A1:A" & UBound(strArr) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strArr)

End Sub
```

also, [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/sort-array.htm) for more examples and tutorial

**EDIT:**
this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196261.aspx) explains why the `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` was used

Comment: Hi mehow, Thanks for the link and code. I tweaked around a bit and don't quite get why `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` is required? My sample seems to work fine without the function

Comment: Hi @Santosh - how does `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` help in the above code. The sample I posted seems to work fine without it.. Does it help with compatibility across older versions?

Comment: @KentPawar please refer to the link in my answer, but `short` story `shorter` (hehe) one dimensional array is in a `horizontal` view so you are converting it into a vertical to be technically correct

Comment: Thanks @mehow.. Looking at it now.

Comment: Argh.. I just realized your code requires `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` as it is output-ing into a column while my code outputs row-wise hehe.. I need a break :p. Thanks, marked it as answered

Comment: Thx man!! It allows this line of code to finally work because of the Transpose method :)

Worksheets("NameOfSheet").ListObjects("NameOfTable").ListColumns(6).DataBodyRange.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrayOfWhatYouWant)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the array in a cell? Remember, you can define a variable equal to an array value: var1 = {v11, v12, v13;v21, v22, v23}

then put "=INDEX( var1, 2, 2)" in any to cell to get value v22.

Comment: Hi @gssi, thanks. I needed the array items into a individual cells separately, but I want to do it using VBA and the target sheet is created dynamically so that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

i had an other way doing this:

```
Dim Arr()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MassHeals")
  Arr = Array("1", "2", "3", "4")
  .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 4).value2 = Arr 
End With
```

The array is set in one line, and i do not use transpose.

Comment: Transpose is needed only when you write a one dimension array in a column, not when you write it in a row as you do here