# vba looping through range writing to csv

Tags: excel, vba, loops, csv

I have written this macro it is supposed to loop through a range and if that range contains a number then copy the offset cells into a csv or to another sheet. Currently when i excute the code it runs through with out breaking however there is no output within my text file nor are there any error messages.

I dont know what is going on? any pointers? please help thanks.

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range 
Dim ofset As String 
Dim filepath As String 

Set rng = Range("F1:F100") 

For Each cell In rng 
  If IsError(cell) Then 
    'MsgBox "cell " & cell.Address & " contains error" 
  ElseIf cell.Value > 0 Then 
    ofset = cell.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 2).Select 'gives you B1:C1 
    ' copy this range to text file 
    filepath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\authors.csv" 
    Open filepath For Output As #2 

    Write #2, cell.Value & ofset 
    Close #2 

  End If
Next cell
MsgBox "The values have been copied"
```

Comment: Do you have the `Next` statement at the end of this code?

Comment: what result do you expect here: `ofset = cell.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 2).Select` taking into account that `Dim ofset As String`?

Comment: i thought id put cell.offset values in a variable. easier to manipulate I thought? And yes there is a next statement at the end @Portland Runner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below seems to copy the offset cell VALUES into the CSV. It gives the desired result. For now this will suffice however I am going to look for a way to take the values and put them in individual columns.

```
  Sub Test3()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim ofset As String
Dim filepath As String

Set rng = Range("F1:F100")

For Each cell In rng
If IsError(cell) Then
'MsgBox "cell " & cell.Address & " contains error"
ElseIf cell.Value > 0 Then
   cell.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 2).Select 'gives you B1:C1
' copy this range to text file
filepath = "C:\Users\Jabaar\Documents\authors.csv"
Open filepath For Append As #2

    Write #2, cell.Value & " " & cell.Offset(, -2).Value & " " & cell.Offset(, -4).Value
Close #2

End If
    Next cell
    MsgBox "The data has been collected"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your extra support @Jimmy Smith

Answer (score 1):

Is the file date updated on each pass?

There may be a null string at the end of the data.
If you're not wanting to only get the last value, change this:

```
Open filepath For Output As #2
```

to

```
Open filepath For Append As #2 

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range  Dim ofset As String  Dim filepath As String 

Set rng = Range("F1:F100") 

For Each cell In rng    If IsError(cell) Then 
    'MsgBox "cell " & cell.Address & " contains error"    ElseIf cell.Value > 0 Then 
    ofset = cell.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 2).Select 'gives you B1:C1 
    ' copy this range to text file 
    filepath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\authors.csv" 
    Open filepath For Output As #2 

    oValues = ""
    For each c in ofset
      oValues=Ovalues & c.value
    next

    Write #2, cell.Value & oValues
    Close #2 

  End If 
Next cell 

MsgBox "The values have been copied"
```

Comment: have change it to append and again nothing seems to happen

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `filepath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\authors.csv"`  does it reach it?

Comment: forgive my ignorance I have tried the breakpoint and it does not reach it. What does this mean?

Comment: It means the conditions don't allow the code to reach that point.  Move the breakpoint higher and step through the module (F8).  I would go with `For Each cell In rng` now

Comment: You've put "I would go with For Each cell in rng now". What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean for debugging, set your breakpoint on that line, to step through and see why it's not hitting your `ElseIf cell.Value > 0 Then`

Comment: Append does write all the value cells however when I try getting the offset cell to appear within the csv it shows the following 1true, 2true, 4true, 3 true; instead I would like the values to be shown as   1 cellcontent1 cellcontent2.   if this makes sense                                                         How can I achieve this?

Comment: It looks like ofset is returning true.  Do you mean to get the identifiers of the range like this `Write #2, Cell.Value & Selection.Address(0, 0)` ?

Comment: I have tried 'selection.address(0,0)' it returns the cell reference instead of the values inside those cells. Like so 1D5:E5, 2D6:E6, 3D7:E7... i would like to get the data in those cells

Comment: Oh!  if you want the values, maybe the function in this answer would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773232/excel-vba-range-to-string-array-in-1-step ?

Comment: the whole function in there? I dont understand which part of the code I can use. Isnt there a simpler way of selecting the offset cells and taking out those values?

Comment: You may be able to do something like this: 

`oValues = ""
For each c in ofset
 oValues=Ovalues & c.value
next

Write #2, cell.Value & oValues`