# Convert Excel Column into String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, excel

I have a column of words in Excel and i want to convert it to a string array, it is a long list and i can't do it manually. How can i do it?

My excel is like:

```
Car
House
Key
Phone
...
```

I want my array to be like:

```
"Car","House","Key","Phone",...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a one-off job or do you want to do that with many different excel files?

Comment: Do you need to do this in Java? (as noted by your tags)

Comment: I just want to do it for 1 time only. And it does not matter how it is done as long as i get the string in that format. I tagged it java because i am going to use that array in java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA: Range to String Array in 1 step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773232/excel-vba-range-to-string-array-in-1-step)

Comment: If vba is an option instead of java the post I flagged as duplicate should solve your problem.

Comment: Well, just use a formular like `=""""&A1&""","` in the second column, then copy-paste that second column into your java source code.

Comment: Is there a way to repeat it from A1 to A241? Since it is a long column, i dont want to do it manually.

Comment: Sure, just mark cell B1, press Ctrl+C, mark B2..B42, press Ctrl+V ... I guess you don't work with Excel that much?!?

Comment: Or you just drag the lower right corner (there should be a small black sqare) of B1 downwards...

Comment: No I don't work too much with Excel but thanks to your clear instructions, i managed to do it! Thanks ammoQ!

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose.Cells for Java](http://www.aspose.com/java/excel-component.aspx) is your friend here. Use this code to read values of a column into a string array.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

Workbook workbook = new Workbook("spreadsheet.xlsx");
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get("Sheet1");
for (Object o: worksheet.getCells().getRows()) {
    Cell cell = ((Row) o).getCellByIndex(0);
    list.add(cell.getStringValueWithoutFormat());
}
```

Import classes from `com.aspose.cells.*`. Enjoy a [free temporary license](http://www.aspose.com/corporate/purchase/temporary-license.aspx) for a limited time before [purchasing](http://www.aspose.com/purchase/).

Disclosure: I am a developer at Aspose.

Answer (score -1):

Try Below mentioned link

[Column to string](https://www.seabreezecomputers.com/excel2array/)