# Trying to convert an excel named range of strings (text with spaces) into a string array

Tags: arrays, string, excel, vba, variant

Trying to convert an excel named range of strings (text with spaces) into a string array to use in a access database query. Basically, pull in list of names from excel, query database using those names, then return data related to those names back to excel.  I found some related answers here:

[Excel VBA: Range to String Array in 1 step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773232/excel-vba-range-to-string-array-in-1-step)

but the "sArray" (string array) is not populating when I run the loop to convert from the variant array to the string array. Here is my code:

```
Dim theRange As Variant
Dim sArray() As String
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = -xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

activeworksheet = ("Sheet2")

theRange = range("SecurityID").Value
size = UBound(theRange)

For i = 1 To 5
    ReDim sArray(1 To 5)
    sArray(i) = CStr(theRange(i, 1))
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. Just a couple of quick things:

```
Sub test()
    Dim theRange As Variant
    Dim sArray() As String
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = -xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    theRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("SecurityID").Value

    ReDim sArray(1 To 5)
    For i = 1 To 5
        sArray(i) = CStr(theRange(1, i))
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

- Specify the sheet name with the Range (ActiveWorksheet is a reserved term)
- You only need to ReDim your destination array once, before your loop
- Setting the `size = UBound(theRange)` is not necessary
- Don't forget to re-enable screen updates, calcs, and alerts at the end

Comment: thank you very much. this is perfect. the main issue was the "Activeworksheet" assignment, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of small error.  This will work on the ActiveSheet:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim theRange As Variant
    Dim sArray() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Range("A1:A5").Name = "SecurityID"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = -xlCalculationManual

    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'activeworksheet = ("Sheet2")

    theRange = Range("SecurityID").Value
    Size = UBound(theRange, 1)
    ReDim sArray(1 To Size)
    For i = 1 To Size
        sArray(i) = CStr(theRange(i, 1))
        MsgBox sArray(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim vSecurityID As Variant
Dim lngCounter As Long

vSecurityID = Range("SecurityID").Value

For lngCounter = LBound(vSecurityID) To UBound(vSecurityID)
    Debug.Print vSecurityID(lngCounter, 1)
Next lngCounter
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Svet. Does this solve my issue though? It looks like it is debug printing to the immediate window the range of strings, but not combining them into a single consolidated string array. Am I missing something?