# VBA copy cell range to public 2D array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA with AutoCAD, and need to extract some data from an Excel Sheet.

Basically I want to:

- Declare a public 2D string array: FULL_TABLE.
- At initialization open the excel document, get a cell range, then
  close the document.
- Put all the values from the cell range to the 2D string array
  FULL_TABLE

What I have so far:

Declared in Module 1:

```
 Public FULL_TABLE() As String
```

Different module:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Excel Path
Dim excelPath As String
excelPath = "O:\myData.xls"

'Open Excel File
Set exapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
exapp.Visible = False
exapp.Workbooks.Open (excelPath)
Set wsheet = exapp.ActiveSheet

'Get cell values
'privateFULL_TABLE is not public and can only be accessed here
'If I try to add values to FULL_TABLE (public) I get errors

Dim privateFULL_TABLE As Variant 
privateFULL_TABLE = wsheet.Range("B5:AV50")

'here I can access values correctly from privateFULL_TABLE

'Close File
exapp.Quit
Set exapp = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Question:**

How can I convert a range of cells to public 2D string array?

Comment: Please see if this is going to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773232/excel-vba-range-to-string-array-in-1-step

Comment: There is nothing specific to AutoCAD in this question.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wasn't sure if it had any effect if it's autocad or not, new to VBA. I've edited the title.

Comment: I found a different approach to the problem. But thank you @Siva , that would probably be the information I needed.