# How to fill an array with strings in VBA and get its lengh?

Tags: vba, excel

How to fill an array with strings in VBA and get its lengh?

For example two cells might contain this info:

A1: "test 1"
A2: "test 2"

```
Dim example As String
Dim arreglito() As String

example = Range("A2").Value


arreglito(0) = example
example= Range("A1").Value
arreglito(1)= example 
MsgBox arreglito(0)
```

> subscript out of range

```
Dim example As String
Dim arreglito() As Variant

example = Range("A2").Value

arreglito(0) = example
MsgBox arreglito(0)
```

> subscript out of range

Comment: `Dim arreglito(1) As String`  you must declare the size of the array before using it.

Comment: it worked fine, is it possible to redefine array size?

Comment: `ReDim`, also the `Array` statement may make that unnecessary.

Comment: Look into Redim and RedimPreserve.  The idea is that the array size must be defined before using.  Or you can use a collection which does not have those constraints.

Comment: or just read the range straight into an array and then take the ubound? Assuming that is what OP means by length?

Comment: ^^^ with that the array must be a variant: `Dim arreglito() As Variant` then you can `arreglito = Range("A1:A2").Value`

Comment: @ScottCraner Indeed. And as didn't want to transfer between arrays added a transpose step of a range variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method of adding a single column range from the worksheet to a string array (transpose may have some size restrictions. 2^16 is it?).

Have used a line by [Flephal](http://%20%20'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773232/excel-vba-range-to-string-array-in-1-step) to get the range into a string array in one step.

```
Sub AddToArray()

Dim arreglito() As String

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("MySheet") 'change as appropriate

Dim srcRange As Range
Set srcRange = ws.Range("A1:A3")

arreglito = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(srcRange), "#"), "#")

MsgBox UBound(arreglito) + 1

End Sub
```

For more than one column transfer via a variant array:

```
Sub AddToArray2()

    Dim arreglito() As String
    Dim sourceArr()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("MySheet") 'change as appropriate

    Dim srcRange As Range
    sourceArr = ws.Range("A1:C3")

    ReDim arreglito(1 To UBound(sourceArr, 1), 1 To UBound(sourceArr, 2))

    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

    For x = LBound(sourceArr, 1) To UBound(sourceArr, 1)
        For y = LBound(sourceArr, 2) To UBound(sourceArr, 2)
            arreglito(x, y) = CStr(sourceArr(x, y))
        Next y
    Next x

    MsgBox UBound(arreglito, 1) & " x " & UBound(arreglito, 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: This also only works on a single column range.  If the range has more than one column it will not work.

Comment: Nag damn it. True.

Answer (score 1):

you can read entire excel range to array, its much faster than reading data from range cell by cell.

```
    Sub testRerad()

        Dim arr As Variant 'no brackets needed, I prefer to use variant
        Dim numOfRows As Long, numOfCols As Long
        arr = Sheets(1).Cells(1).Resize(10, 1).value 'arr will contain data from range A1:A10

        'or
        arr = Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.value 'arr will contain data from all continous data startig with A1

        'get dimensions
        numOfRows = UBound(a)
        numOfCols = UBound(a, 2)

    End Sub
```

be warned that this will always create multidimensional array (even if only 1 column) with dimensions 1 to y, 1 to x