# Compare two CSV Documents using VBA Copy-Paste Script

Tags: excel, vba, csv, compare

since a week I try to succeed on my topic, but I cant find any acceptable solution. I mean, ... I have a working solution, but comparing only takes about half a day :-S

Precondition:
Both csv-files are already copy-pasted into local workbook. they are present and ready to play with them. each file has ~6000 rows and 4 columns.
column A: documentname/version
column B: subject1
column C: subject2
column D: boolean-artefact
both csv files have same structure.
column A includes a documentname and its latest version.
each row contains a combination of: documentname/version, subj1, subj2, boolean

Examples of CSV_old new including comments/change for csv_new in column_E

```
Document/Version    Subj1   Subj2   BOOLEAN 
DOC_1/Vers1         FUN     GERMANY FALSE   
DOC_2/Vers3         FUN     GERMANY TRUE    
DOC_2/Vers3         FUN     UK      TRUE    <- to be deleted in CSV_new
DOC_2/Vers3         FUN     FRANCE  TRUE    
DOC_3/Vers7         ACTION  GERMANY FALSE   <- Version Update in CSV_new
DOC_4/Vers4         MOVIE   UK      TRUE    
DOC_6/Vers1         HELP    SPAIN   FALSE   
DOC_7/Vers2         FUN     GERMANY FALSE   <- boolean: true in CSV_new
DOC_8/Vers5         FUN FRANCE  TRUE    <- Subj1: ACTION instead of FUN
```

CSV_new

```
Document/Version    Subj1   Subj2   BOOLEAN 
DOC_1/Vers1         FUN     GERMANY FALSE   
DOC_2/Vers3         FUN     GERMANY TRUE    
DOC_2/Vers3         FUN     UK      TRUE    
DOC_2/Vers3         FUN     FRANCE  TRUE    
DOC_3/Vers9         ACTION  GERMANY FALSE   <- Version Updated
DOC_4/Vers4         MOVIE   UK      TRUE    
DOC_5/Vers5         DANGER  UK      FALSE   <- new/added Row in CSV_new
DOC_6/Vers1         HELP    SPAIN   FALSE   
DOC_7/Vers2         FUN     GERMANY FALSE   <- boolean updated to true
DOC_8/Vers5         ACTION  FRANCE  TRUE    <- Subj1: ACTION instead of FUN
```

Aim:
Compare two CSV files (both derived from database). Each file is a derived version from a huge database (extract). I would like to check an older csv file (e.g version 2.0, csv_old) against a newer on (e.g. version 4.1, csv_new).

> This way I would like to see the differents between both derived versions (extracts) of the database. There can  be new inserted/added lines as well as deleted lines.

So far I got a code which is working, but takes sooooooo much time. I paste a kind of pseudo code to give you an imagination about my approach (it does only contain one step of comparison):

For rowInOldCSV = 3 To Sheets("_ws_oldCSV").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

```
Set findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA = Sheets(givenActiveWS).Cells.Find(Sheets("_ws_oldCSV").Range("A" & rowInOldCSV & ":D" & rowInOldCSV).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
Set findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA_withoutVers = Sheets(givenActiveWS).Cells.Find(Left(Sheets("_ws_oldCSV").Cells(rowInOldCSV, 1).Value, Len(Sheets("_ws_oldCSV").Cells(rowInOldCSV, 1).Value) - 5), LookIn:=xlValues)


If Not findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA Is Nothing Then
    'document/version found!

    firstAddress = findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA.Address
    Do
         'if subj1+subj2 are same
        If (Sheets(givenActiveWS).Cells(findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA.Row, 2).Value = Sheets("_ws_oldCSV").Cells(rowInOldCSV, 2).Value) And _
           (Sheets(givenActiveWS).Cells(findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA.Row, 3).Value = Sheets("_ws_oldCSV").Cells(rowInOldCSV, 3).Value) Then '....and boolean-value the same

            'Sheets("_ws_oldCSV").Range("A" & rowInOldCSV & ":D" & rowInOldCSV).Copy 'takes even longer
            'Sheets(givenActiveWS).Cells(findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA.Row, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Sheets(givenActiveWS).Cells(findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA.Row, 6).Value = Sheets("_ws_oldCSV").Cells(rowInOldCSV, 1).Value
            Sheets(givenActiveWS).Cells(findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA.Row, 7).Value = Sheets("_ws_oldCSV").Cells(rowInOldCSV, 2).Value
            Sheets(givenActiveWS).Cells(findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA.Row, 8).Value = Sheets("_ws_oldCSV").Cells(rowInOldCSV, 3).Value
            Sheets(givenActiveWS).Cells(findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA.Row, 9).Value = Sheets("_ws_oldCSV").Cells(rowInOldCSV, 4).Value

            'leave loop
            Exit Do
        End If
        Set findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA = Sheets(givenActiveWS).Cells.FindNext(findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA)
    Loop While Not findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA Is Nothing And findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA.Address <> firstAddress

Else
    'document/version not found
    If Not findSameDocumentNumberInColumnA_withoutVers Is Nothing Then
        'document found, looks like new version
        'mark it with yellow to show updated version
    Else
        'unkown document, means  new introduced since csv_old
        'copy it under last item in RowF
        '
    End If
End If
next rowInOldCSV
```

So far to my approach. I saw two different ones:
http://www.ms-office-forum.net/forum/showthread.php?t=279399
and
[Excel VBA: Range to String Array in 1 step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773232/excel-vba-range-to-string-array-in-1-step)
both seems to work quite well and veeeery fast, but unfortunately I am not able to use it for my scenario.

I guess, I have to put the values from column into string-array to start a comparison? I am out of ideas and have no clue how to handle Column-Values into String-Arrays. Sorry, ...

You might help me?

Result of comparison: would be nice to write stuff into CSV_new.

```
Doc/Vers       Subj1    Subj2    BOOLEAN    Doc    Subj1    Subj1    Boolean
DOC_1/Vers1    FUN      GERMANY  FALSE      -       -       -           -
DOC_2/Vers3    FUN      GERMANY  TRUE       -       -       -           -
DOC_2/Vers3    FUN      UK       TRUE      Deleted  -       -           -
DOC_2/Vers3    FUN      FRANCE   TRUE      -        -       -           -
DOC_3/Vers9    ACTION   GERMANY  FALSE     Updated  -       -           -
DOC_4/Vers4    MOVIE    UK       TRUE      -        -       -           -
DOC_5/Vers5    DANGER   UK       FALSE     New      -       -           -
DOC_6/Vers1    HELP     SPAIN    FALSE     -        -       -           -
DOC_7/Vers2    FUN      GERMANY  TRUE      -        -       -           X
DOC_8/Vers5    ACTION   FRANCE   TRUE      -        X       -           -
```

Many, many thanks in advance for your effort!!!!! :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will generate 2 sets of results: one for `Sheet1` (old), the other for `Sheet2` (new)

- Set 1 - `Sheet1` will show the records **`missing from Sheet2`**
- Set 2 - `Sheet2` will show the records **`missing from Sheet1`**
- Both sets will show updated records

It uses nested dictionaries (detailed bellow)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CompareCSVs()    '1 = Old, 2 = New; UsedRange starts at A1

    Const LC1 = 4           'D - LastCol in Old
    Const LC2 = 4           'D - LastCol in New

    Dim ur1 As Range, arr1 As Variant, dv1 As Object
    Dim ur2 As Range, arr2 As Variant, dv2 As Object

    Set ur1 = Sheet1.UsedRange  'Or: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("csv_old").UsedRange
    Set ur2 = Sheet2.UsedRange  'Or: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("csv_new").UsedRange
    arr1 = ur1
    arr2 = ur2
    Set dv1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dv2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim urRes1 As Range, urRes2 As Range, arrRes1 As Variant, arrRes2 As Variant

    Set urRes1 = ur1.Offset(1, LC1).Resize(ur1.Rows.Count - 1, LC1 + 1) 'Exclude Headers
    Set urRes2 = ur2.Offset(1, LC2).Resize(ur2.Rows.Count - 1, LC2 + 1) 'Exclude Headers
    urRes1.ClearContents        'Clear results
    urRes2.ClearContents
    arrRes1 = urRes1
    arrRes2 = urRes2

    SetDictionaries dv1, arr1, LC1
    SetDictionaries dv2, arr2, LC2:     'ShowAllItems dv1:   ShowAllItems dv2

    CompareData dv1, dv2, arrRes2
    CompareData dv2, dv1, arrRes1

    urRes1 = arrRes1
    urRes2 = arrRes2
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub SetDictionaries(ByRef d As Object, ByRef arr As Variant, ByVal ubC As Long)

    Dim r As Long, c As Long, k As String

    For r = 2 To UBound(arr)
        For c = 1 To ubC
            k = k & arr(r, c) & "|"
            d(Left(k, Len(k) - 1)) = 0
        Next
        k = vbNullString
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CompareData(ByRef d1 As Variant, ByRef d2 As Variant, ByRef res As Variant)

    Dim r As Long, c As Long, itm As Variant, sp As Variant, k As Variant

    r = 1
    For Each itm In d2
        sp = Split(itm, "|")
        c = UBound(sp) + 1
        If Not d1.Exists(itm) Then
            If Len(res(r, 1)) = 0 Then
                res(r, 1) = IIf(c = 1, "Missing: ", "Updated: ")
                res(r, c + 1) = sp(c - 1)
            Else
                If res(r, 1) = "Updated: " Then res(r, c + 1) = sp(c - 1)
            End If
        End If
        If c = 4 Then r = r + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub ShowAllItems(ByRef d As Object)

    Dim x As Variant

    For Each x In d
        Debug.Print x   'Space$(5), String$(5, "-")
    Next
    Debug.Print
End Sub
```

---

Dictionaries, when ready to be compared

[image: Dictionaries]

Before

[image: Before]

After

[image: After]

Note: The sample data you provided is not the same as in the description

```
CSV_old

Document/Version Subj1  Subj2   BOOLEAN 
DOC_1/Vers1      FUN    GERMANY FALSE                                 <- Correct
DOC_2/Vers3      FUN    GERMANY TRUE                                  <- Correct
DOC_2/Vers3      FUN    UK      TRUE  <- to be deleted in CSV_new     <- Exists in new
DOC_2/Vers3      FUN    FRANCE  TRUE                                  <- Correct
DOC_3/Vers7      ACTION GERMANY FALSE <- Version Update in CSV_new    <- This not in new
DOC_4/Vers4      MOVIE  UK      TRUE                                  <- Correct
DOC_6/Vers1      HELP   SPAIN   FALSE                                 <- Correct  
DOC_7/Vers2      FUN    GERMANY FALSE <- boolean: true in CSV_new     <- FALSE in new
DOC_8/Vers5      FUN    FRANCE  TRUE  <- Subj1: ACTION instead of FUN <- Correct

CSV_new

Document/Version Subj1  Subj2   BOOLEAN 
DOC_1/Vers1      FUN    GERMANY FALSE                                 <- Correct
DOC_2/Vers3      FUN    GERMANY TRUE                                  <- Correct  
DOC_2/Vers3      FUN    UK      TRUE                                  <- Exists in new
DOC_2/Vers3      FUN    FRANCE  TRUE                                  <- Correct   
DOC_3/Vers9      ACTION GERMANY FALSE <- Version Updated              <- New record
DOC_4/Vers4      MOVIE  UK      TRUE                                  <- Correct
DOC_5/Vers5      DANGER UK      FALSE <- new/added Row in CSV_new     <- Correct
DOC_6/Vers1      HELP   SPAIN   FALSE                                 <- Correct
DOC_7/Vers2      FUN    GERMANY FALSE <- boolean updated to true      <- FALSE in new
DOC_8/Vers5      ACTION FRANCE  TRUE  <- Subj1: ACTION instead of FUN <- Correct
```

Comment: **MAAAAANY THANKS**, thats so good! :o) And its so fast! Unfortunately this thing about using 'CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")' I dont understand at all. Result "Missing:" concludes added and deleted rows in the same way/meaning. Is there a chance to make a difference between new/added rows and deleted ones?

Comment: I'm glad it helped ! but I'm not sure what you meant by making a difference between new and deleted rows: `Sheet1` will show all missing rows from `Sheet2` - this shows all `deleted` records from CSV_new. Then, `Sheet2` will show all missing rows from `Sheet1` - this shows all `new` records from CSV_new. You cannot show new **and** deleted records in one sheet, because you'd have to insert the missing row, to show that is missing (maybe I'm not understanding correctly)

Comment: @stoeven - BTW - can you give me an idea how long it takes now? (how many total rows in old, and how many total rows in new?). I didn't have proper data for testing thousands of rows. Thanks

Comment: Oh dear, you are right - got it :o)  So, ... i will keep this as a solution. Right now I have approx. 5900 rows in both and it takes about 2 seconds until finish. **Brilliant approach** working with these Dictionarys. But to be honest, need to Bing/Google that again to understand its structure to go further on my own. Many thanks again for your effort you put into this topic.

Comment: You are welcome! If you work with a lot of data you will be able to improve performance significantly with `arrays`, `dictionaries`, and `collections`. The key thing to remember is to keep interactions with ranges at a minimum: read the entire sheet into an array: `Dim arr as Variant: arr = Sheet1.UsedRange`, make the changes to the array the same way you'd make them to the sheet: `Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = "Test"`, is the same as `arr(1, 1) = "Test"`, then place the entire array back on the UsedRange: `Sheet1.UsedRange = arr`