# Array of unique values from range - Without any loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

At risk of being of topic, I decided to share some code, [Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). If the general opinion is such that this would be off-topic I'll be happy to delete if need be.

---

***<sub>Background</sub>***

Having a `Range` object holding a certain amount of values I would want to pull those values into an array. The conventional way (at least to me) would be to use `""scripting.dictionary"`, loop through a `Range`, or rather an `Array` in memory, to add these values into a uniques list.

While that works, I wanted to see if there is a method to pull an array of unique items without any loop.

---

***<sub>Sample</sub>***

Imagine the following data in `A1:A8`:

```
Vals
A
B
A
B
C
C
B
```

---

***<sub>Question</sub>***

To retrieve a 1D-array of unique items `{A,B,C}`, how would we go about doing this without a loop?

Comment: Use in conjuction with the range 'remove duplicates': 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773232/excel-vba-range-to-string-array-in-1-step

Comment: @Tragamor, removing duplicates means altering and working through worksheet cells. I wanted to do this through memory for further usage. What does the link have to do with this btw (despite it being an interesting read)?

Comment: Yeah - I was thinking about it afterwards and realised you would need to copy the range to a dummy worksheet and manipulate that. For reference; the link has an answer of mine where you populate a range into an array in one line avoiding loops which is why it is in there. The use of a dictionary is probably the better solution, but there are alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***<sub>Uniques - Dictionary</sub>***

A very solid (and fast) way of returning a 1D-array of unique values would be to use a conventional [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) object as below:

```
Sub UniquesDictionary()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long
Dim arr As Variant
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sheet1

    'Find the last used row
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A2:A" & lr).Value

End With

    'Loop through memory and fill dictionary
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        dict(arr(x, 1)) = 1
    Next x

    'Pull unique items into a 1D-array
    arr = dict.Keys

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Uniques - Evaluate</sub>***

Whilst the above works. The wish was to avoid any loop. The way to do this is to use [`.Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate), see below:

```
Sub UniquesEvaluate()

Dim lr As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With Sheet1

    'Find the last used row
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Get array of unique values
    arr = Filter(.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(If(Row(A2:A" & lr & ")<>MATCH(A2:A" & lr & ",A2:A" & lr & ",0)+1,""|"",A2:A" & lr & "))"), "|", False)

End With

End Sub
```

It might seem like a long formula but it really isn't that impressive and boils down to:

```
=IF(ROW(A2:A8)<>MATCH(A2:A8,A2:A8,0)+1,"|",A2:A8)
```

The `TRANSPOSE` is only there to return a 1D-array for `FILTER` to work with.

- The inital formula will only return those values that are sitting on the rows where they are first encountered through `MATCH`, otherwise it would return a pipe-symbol.
- Thus `TRANSPOSE(<formula>)` returns a 1D-array, e.g.: `{A,B,|,|,C,|,|}`
- [`Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filter-function) then uses this 1D-array as an input, returning an array filtering out those pipe-symbols using `FALSE` in the "include" parameter, e.g: `Filter(<arr>,"|",FALSE)` > `{A,B,C}`.

---

***<sub>Comparison</sub>***

This would only have real purpose if this method would be equally as fast as the more conventional `Dictionary` so I did a small comparison. As far as my testing goes, there was no really noticable timing difference (around 0 seconds), but since in essence the `Evaluate` is a `CSE` formula, larger datasets will get noticable timing differences above let's say 2000 rows of data.

Hopefully this is usefull to those working with smaller datasets.