# How to assign range in a string VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to highlight words in a cell based on the values in another cells. It works perfectly when I assign `FindW = Range("X1")` . However the code does not seem to work when I assign range e.g:**("X1:X1000")** to the string value **FindW** and I could not find a way to fix this.

Does anyone have any idea?

See the code below:

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim FindW As String
Dim xTmp As String
Dim x As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Übersicht")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
    

With ws

FindW = Range("X1:X1000")
y = Len(FindW)



For Each Rng In Range("C:H")
  With Rng
    m = UBound(Split(Rng.Value, FindW))
    If m > 0 Then
      xTmp = ""
      For x = 0 To m - 1
        xTmp = xTmp & Split(Rng.Value, FindW)(x)
        .Characters(Start:=Len(xTmp) + 1, Length:=y).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        xTmp = xTmp & FindW
      Next
    End If
  End With
Next Rng
     
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you expecting the string `FindW` to be? Are you for example trying to concatenate the values in that range? `FindW = Range("X1")` assigns the value of that range to the string variable. However `FindW = Range("X1:X1000")` doesn't work because you cannot assign a multi-cell range to a `String` variable

Comment: Also you're looping `For Each Rng In Range("C:H")` without any `Exit For` inside the loop. That's looping millions of times more than you should. Try to establish the used range beforehand and only loop through this range.

Comment: ```FindW``` are values that i would like to find in the cells "X1:X1000". I am not trying to concatenate the values in the range. Yes I would like to assign a multi-cell range to a ```String```  variable. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: No there's not way to do that. You have to loop through the range "X1:X1000" and assign each cell value to `FindW`

Comment: Please think about what you said: "Yes I would like to assign a multi-cell range to a String variable". What are you expecting the string's value would be?

Comment: To summary this: you need to highlight cells in range `C:H` if they contain any of the words in the Range  `X1:X1000` ?

Comment: @Damian yes! exactly.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry sorry if i am not very familiar with the terms since i am very new to programming. Btw I just loop through the range "X1:X1000" and it works. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: No need to be sorry at all. I was only trying to understand your rationale so that I can suggest something that would work. Anyway, I'm glad you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put the values of a `Range` of multiple cells directly into a single `String` variable.  However, you can create a `String` Array and store each cell value individually in the `String` Array.

The easiest solution is to just use a `Variant` variable, and put the range values directly in it, like this :

```
Dim mrange As Range
Dim mVariant As Variant
mVariant = myRange.Value
```

If you really need your variable to be a `String`, there are multiples ways to do so:

For example, you can loop through each cell of the Array using something like :

```
For each mCell in mRange.Cells
    mString(i) = mCell.Value
    i = i + 1
Next mCell
```

mRange being your Range, and mString being a String Array.  This solution requires for you to know how many cells are in the Range, since the String array needs to be defined with a size.

If you don't know the size of your Range, you can add a step and use a Variant variable.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6779357/11071704).

Comment: Why not work directly with a `Variant`? What would be the advantage in this case? `mString = mRange.Value`

Comment: I kept the idea of the string from his code, since I don't know if it is important for him, but sure directly work with a Variant is the best solution. I'll add a line